# SQL: Optimizing Recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

**Example table structure:**

```
EmployeeId  TeamleaderId  TopTeamleaderId   LEVEL   ParentTree    CompanyId  
1           0             0                 0       NULL          1
2           1             1                 1       2>1           1
3           2             1                 2       3>2>1         1
```

`TeamleaderId` is `foreignKey` reference to `EmployeeId` in the same table

**Goal:** 
Whenever a row is inserted in the table with `EmployeeId`, `TeamleaderId`, `CompanyId` automatically populate `TopTeamleaderId`, `LEVEL` and `ParentTree` with `AFTER INSERT` trigger

**Code:**

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT EmployeeId, TeamleaderId,0 AS [Level], CAST(EmployeeId AS varchar(100)) AS Heirarchy, TopTeamleaderId
  FROM dbo.Employee
  WHERE EmployeeId IN (SELECT EmployeeId FROM Employee WHERE TeamleaderId IS NULL 
    AND CompanyId IN(SELECT DISTINCT CompanyId FROM INSERTED))

  UNION ALL

  SELECT mgr.EmployeeId, mgr.TeamleaderId, CTE.[Level] +1 AS [Level], 
        CAST(( CAST(mgr.EmployeeId AS VARCHAR(100)) + '>' + CTE.Heirarchy) AS varchar(100)) AS Heirarchy, CTE.TopTeamleaderId
  FROM CTE
    INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS mgr
      ON TaskCTE.EmployeeId = mgr.ParentTeamleaderId
)
UPDATE Employee SET [LEVEL] = TC.[LEVEL], ParentTree = TC.Heirarchy, TopTeamleaderId = TC.TopTeamleaderId
FROM dbo.Employee AS Employee
JOIN (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE EmployeeId IN(SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeId FROM INSERTED) AND ParentTeamleaderId IS NOT NULL) TC
ON 
Employee.EmployeeId = TC.EmployeeId
```

**Problem:**
Imagine there are like 1000000 employees in a company, this query would take a long time to execute. How to optimize it so that only the parents of the inserted row are taken in to account?

Comment: What is your buisness rule to do that? Please explain and make an example.

Comment: See rules are not clear nor purpose of your table design.Below script is OK but above your script is definitely wrong even from Recursive CTE point of view.It can be optimized too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive CTE's are great, but as you can see the perfomance can suffer with larger hierarchies. It is my firm belief that **there is no shame in temp tables**.

The following will generate a 200K point hierarchy in 0.784 seconds.

**Example**

```
Select EmployeeId
      ,TeamleaderId
      ,Lvl=1
      ,TopTeamleaderId = 0   
      ,ParentTree=cast(EmployeeId as varchar(500)) 
      ,CompanyID
 Into  #TempBld 
 From  Employee 
 Where TeamleaderId is null

Declare @Cnt int=1
While @Cnt<=30     --<< Set Your Max Level
    Begin
        Insert Into #TempBld 
        Select A.EmployeeId
              ,A.TeamleaderId
              ,B.Lvl+1
              ,IIF(B.Lvl=1,B.EmployeeId,B.TopTeamleaderId)
              ,concat(A.EmployeeId,'>',B.ParentTree)
              ,A.CompanyID
         From  Employee A
         Join  #TempBld B on (B.Lvl=@Cnt and A.TeamleaderId=B.EmployeeId)
        Set @Cnt=@Cnt+1
    End

--Select * from #TempBld Order by ParentTree
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: I am still going through the answer however, on the first glance the generated `ParentTree` is opposite to what I would like. For example for `EmployeeId = 16` in your example the `ParentTree` should be `16>1`

Comment: @ShyamalParikh Corrected the sequence of ParentTree