# CTE is taking too long to execute. A Need a faster alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Below are the sample table :

```
#master_table
master_id   
----------
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8

#child_table
master_id   child_id    tracking_number     parent_id   source_type     condition
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           A           123                             Wood        Excellent
    2           B           456                             Iron          Great
    3           A1          789                 A           Plastic        Bad
    4           B1          101                 B           Wood          Great
    5           B2          112                 B           Plastic       Good
    6           B3          113                 B           Jello          Bad
    7           C           114                             Iron          Great
    8           D           115                             Wood           Good


Expected Result
master_id   child_id    parent_tracking_number  parent_type 
------------------------------------------------------------    
    1           A           123                     Wood
    2           B           456                     Iron
    3           A1          123                     Wood
    4           B1          456                     Iron
    5           B2          456                     Iron
    6           B3          456                     Iron
    7           C           114                     Iron
    8           D           115                     Wood
```

So based on the above table, i need to get the most top parent value for some column. The parent/child level can be unlimited.

Here is the code that i have for now but its taking a long time to execute (approximately 45 seconds) when the parent has great great grand child.. FYI, it has around 30k row in the result.

```
; WITH data_cte AS (
    SELECT 
        a.master_id,
        b.child_id, 
        '' as parent_tracking_number,
        b.source_type as parent_type
    FROM 
        #master_table as a with(nolock)
        inner join #child_table as b with(nolock) on b.master_id = a.master_id
    WHERE 
        b.parent_id is null

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        a.master_id, 
        b.child_id, 
        e.tracking_number as parent_tracking_number,
        e.parent_type
    FROM 
        #master_table as a with(nolock)
        inner join #child_table as b with(nolock) on b.master_id = a.master_id
        inner join data_cte as e on b.parent_id = e.child_id            
)

SELECT * FROM data_cte
```

So I need a faster execution alternative for this. How can I optimize this?

Comment: It probably doesn't make any difference for a temp table but splattering NOLOCK all over is not a great idea. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere. Also those aliases will make things difficult. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3 For the task at hand this is doing recursion with apparently an unknown number of levels. It is going to be slow because of all the iterations that have to happen.

Comment: You might be interested on creating using datatype [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16) it's supported in every SQL Server version and has a [GetRoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/getroot-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) method

Comment: If you create proper indexes on #master_table /#child_table.master_id it should go faster. Btw, don't think you need to join #master in the second UNION ALL part. @SeanLange, NOLOCK is like pushing turbo button on 486 PC, instant speed

Comment: In truth, the fact you've used `NOLOCK` on temporary tables, which is somewhere it *literally* makes no sense does suggest that you don't know what it does and shouldn't be using it. It's not a "go faster" button, and should very rarely be used.

Comment: Performance questions require an execution plan - please provide this using Paste The Plan

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44874944/sql-optimizing-recursive-cte/44875602#44875602   If you provided the DML for your table I would have been happy to customize it

Comment: @siggemannen it's more like turning on the turbo button in a car that is red lining already and then never turning it back off. It has some minimal short term performance benefits but long term it is going to bite you. That hint has so many downsides it outweighs the minor benefits almost every single time.

Answer (score 0):

Only considering the query itself and try to optimize it, try following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX1184574488 ON data_cte(child_id,tracking_number,parent_type);
  -- E(DRIVEN): INDEX_MATCHING,INDEX_ONLY
  -- E(DRIVE): INDEX_MATCHING,INDEX_ONLY
  CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX0504418253 ON child_table(parent_id,master_id);
  -- B(DRIVEN): INDEX_MATCHING
  -- B(DRIVE): INDEX_MATCHING
  CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX0589055627 ON child_table(master_id,child_id);
  -- B(DRIVEN): INDEX_MATCHING
  CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX1374327951 ON master_table(master_id);
  -- A(DRIVEN): INDEX_MATCHING,INDEX_ONLY
  -- A(DRIVEN): INDEX_MATCHING,INDEX_ONLY
```

Explanation of `E(DRIVEN): INDEX_MATCHING,INDEX_ONLY`(how the index helps. )

- E: is the table reference in the query
- Drive/Driven: means this table play a drive/driven role in the join,
- INDEX_MATCHING: the index will matching the equal predicates
- INDEX_ONLY: this index is a covering index

Comment: This is not valid t-sql. I can't find this syntax in any DBMS.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, i copied the recommendations without editing from the tool i built, explanations added.