# How to make this T-SQL CTE run faster

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child, hierarchy

I am hoping to improve the performance of my Parent/Child CTE. I am wondering if there is a new, better, faster way. The CTE simply traversess a Parent-Child Tree that now contains about 400k people. In SSMS this runs in about 5 to 8 seconds.

Each person is related to one another through a classic CHILD ID (UserID in my code) vs PARENT ID (SponsorID in my code). The UserID is the Primary Key with Clustered Index called PK_UserID. The SponsorID has a NON Clustered index called IX_SponsorID.

Paste The Plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyaDlDkC3

```
   -- Engine To Build Parent/Child
    ;
WITH CTE
AS
    (
        -- The Anchor Person 
        SELECT  UserID
           ,SponsorID
               ,0 AS Level
        FROM CCMUsers 
        WHERE UserID = 45
    
        UNION ALL
        
        -- The Recursive People 
        SELECT e.UserID
              ,e.SponsorID
          ,CTE.Level + 1
        FROM CCMUsers AS e
        INNER JOIN CTE ON e.SponsorID = CTE.UserID
)
select * from CTE
```

Comment: T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: Can you [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) please?

Comment: 400K isn't a lot of data, provided the proper indexes exist. Without indexing, even 5K can be "a lot" for a bad query. The amount of nesting can also affect performance. If `UserID 45` has 100K children, the query will be slow. SQL Server offers the [hierarhcyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/tutorial-using-the-hierarchyid-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16) type to speed up hierarchical queries. The `hierarchyid` is essentially a hierarchical path in binary form, eg `/45/345/1/5678`. Searching for a node's children is effectively a range search, not recursion

Comment: If the indexes are there, the execution plan is optimal but the nesting is too deep, the only way to improve performance would be to move to `hierarchyid`. In the [Find Descendants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/lesson-2-creating-and-managing-data-in-a-hierarchical-table?view=sql-server-ver16#find-subordinate-nodes) example the `OrgNode` is the hierarchyID column. It's enough to write `select OrgNode.GetLevel(), * FROM SomeTable where OrgNode.IsDesendantOf(@root) = 1;`

Comment: For performance help, we need at a minimum: the tables and index definitions, and the query plan (please share via PasteThePlan.com). We can't answer otherwise.

Comment: From the query it transpires that each person can have one sponsor at the most. Is this correct? If that's the case, how many levels of sponsors can a person have, as in this case `UserID = 45`?

Comment: Are you seeing an index seek on `IX_SponsorID` in the recursive part? Does the plan have lookups there also indicating that you should consider  `INCLUDE`-ing the `UserID` column in that index?

Comment: Thank you to those who have already offered info. I will post an execution plan shortly. ID 45 is the top of the world and currently has 375,000+ children through about 100 levels. Again, I am just looking for you experts to show me a better way or expose any weaknesses.

Comment: At a guess, you are going to want indexes `CCMUsers (UserID) INCLUDE (SponsorID)` and `CCMUsers (SponsorID) INCLUDE (UserID)` but we need to really see that info I asked for

Comment: What is the consumer of this query going to do with 375,000+ rows?

Comment: I think this is what you asked me to do on Paste The Plan. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyaDlDkC3

Comment: Here is another approach that is much faster than the recursive cte.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44874944/sql-optimizing-recursive-cte/44875602#44875602

Comment: Shame Recursive CTEs are always so RBAR and they always do nested loops row by row and don't have any other options - such as whole levels at a time

Comment: That plan has seeks of covering indexes in both the anchor and recursive part of the CTE so is probably as good as it will get without changing approach to not use a recursive CTE

Comment: @AaronBertrand I use this particular CTE to extract the UserID's of a particular Genealogy. In this example UserID 45 is the very top of the tree structure.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti isn't that essentially a hand-rolled hierarhcyid ?

Comment: @JerryMattox in this case no approach would really help because you're loading the entire table in memory. `hierarchyid` would be *faster* than the CTE but you're still loading 95% of the data in memory, so its performance would similar to just loading everything. You'd avoid the 5% unwanted rows at least, and get a fast calculation of `Level`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes.   Completely optional.   But I use this approach building LARGE hierarchies.   We tend to have custom presentation sequences and I use a padded value for sorting

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, that's a nice technique. I would probably add if @@rowcount = 0 break code to bail out early. And index on the temp table

Comment: @siggemannen. Good idea!   In the middle of some renovations, but I will certainly circle back on this

Comment: If ``ID 45 is the top of the world ``,you may start anchor from ``WHERE SponsorID = 45``. This my be significantly faster.   (After, include UserId=45 as additional union).

Comment: @ValNik - this won't make any difference. Either way at some point or other it will end up running that `WHERE SponsorID = 45` predicate and adding all the rows to a stack spool.

Answer (score 2):

Your plan has seeks of covering indexes in both the anchor and recursive part of the CTE so is probably as good as it will get with that approach.

From the information in the comments I created the following test data with similar overall depth and quantity.

```
CREATE TABLE CCMUsers
  (
     UserID    INT IDENTITY(45, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
     SponsorID INT NULL INDEX IX_SponsorID /*Includes CI key so covering*/,
     Lvl       TINYINT /*Helper for data creation */
  );

INSERT CCMUsers
       (Lvl)
VALUES (1)

DECLARE @Lvl TINYINT = 1

WHILE @Lvl < 100
  BEGIN
      INSERT CCMUsers
             (SponsorID,
              Lvl)
      SELECT UserID,
             @Lvl + 1
      FROM   CCMUsers
      WHERE  Lvl = @Lvl
      UNION ALL
      SELECT UserID,
             @Lvl + 1
      FROM   CCMUsers
      WHERE  Lvl = @Lvl
             AND ( @Lvl % 7 = 0 OR @Lvl % 47 = 0 )

      SET @Lvl = @Lvl + 1
  END
```

When running the query in the question (returns 425,209 rows) but with a `SELECT * INTO #TEMP from CTE` to remove from the equation any delays added by SSMS processing these rows elapsed time was 4235 ms.

Trying a looping approach was worse - at around 10 seconds. This probably wasn't helped by the spool for Haloween protection on the insert to `#Results`. I would consider this if there were few levels/no useful index for the recursive part (so could get a hash join for a level at a time for example) but this is not the case here.

```
SET statistics time OFF
SET nocount OFF

DECLARE @Level SMALLINT = 0;

CREATE TABLE #Results
  (
     UserID    INT,
     SponsorID INT,
     Level     SMALLINT,
     PRIMARY KEY (Level, UserID)
  )

INSERT #Results
-- The Anchor Person 
SELECT UserID,
       SponsorID,
       @Level AS Level
FROM   CCMUsers
WHERE  UserID = 45

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
  BEGIN
      SET @Level +=1;

      INSERT #Results
      -- The Recursive People 
      SELECT e.UserID,
             e.SponsorID,
             @Level
      FROM   CCMUsers AS e
             INNER JOIN #Results r
                     ON e.SponsorID = r.UserID
      WHERE  r.Level = @Level - 1
  END

DROP TABLE #Results
```

After [changing the table structure to use `HierarchyId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/lesson-1-converting-a-table-to-a-hierarchical-structure?view=sql-server-ver16) there was a decent improvement, partly as it ran in parallel and partly as it did less work overall (CPU time = 1189 ms,  elapsed time = 899 ms)

I used table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCMUsers2](
    [UserID] [int] IDENTITY UNIQUE,
    [path] [hierarchyid] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Level AS [path].GetLevel() PERSISTED,
    index ix_Level_path UNIQUE (Level, [path]) INCLUDE([UserID])
);
```

And query

```
declare @root hierarchyid = (SELECT path FROM [dbo].[CCMUsers2] WHERE UserID = 45)

SELECT t1.UserID,
       t2.UserID          AS SponsorID,
       t1.path.GetLevel() AS Level
INTO   #TEMP
FROM   CCMUsers2 t1 WITH (FORCESEEK)
       LEFT JOIN CCMUsers2 t2
              ON t2.path = t1.path.GetAncestor(1)
WHERE  t1.path.IsDescendantOf(@root) = 1
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

The `t1.path.IsDescendantOf(@root)` is able to be converted to a range seek on the `path` column though I needed to add the `FORCESEEK` column to show that as the whole table is a descendant in this case. The `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` was to get accurate cardinality estimates and an adequate memory grant for the hash join.

[image]

I did also try using the `UserID` in the `HierachyId` itself to avoid the self join but calling `.ToString()` on that and extracting the right part was considerably slower.

Comment: Thank you Martin Smith for you efforts in this matter. I am back on this project and plan to test and try all your code. You're amaing. -- Jerry Mattox